# Confirm email after Customer signup magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am developing a e-commerce mobile application using magento 2 REST apis.

The sign up api is working perfectly.

**Signup Api->**   `http://{{domain_name}}/index.php/rest/V1/customers`

Also I  changed my system configuration for confirming the mail is.

1.Go to **System** -> **Configuration** -> **CUSTOMERS** -> **Customer Configuration**

2.Click **Create New Account Options**

3.Set **Require Emails Confirmation** to **Yes**

4.Click  **Save Config**.

Here the problem,after signup.The confirmation mail is not sending to the customer.Please help me?

Comment: do you know where i will get expiry setting for the same?

Comment: First, enable Magento log. If any mail error exists then it is displayed in exception log and system log. Feel free to ask still not working.